# How to Encrypt and Decrypt Text message in react native and backend Node js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

i have Messaging app in react native and messages coming from nodejs back end which is encrypted but when i try to decrypt in my react native app using react-native-crypto-js it is not working.
so i want to use a library that works on both nodejs backend and React native app .

any solutions?

Comment: What is the encryption that you use on your back end?

Comment: cryptography.js

Comment: You mean CryptoJS: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js ?

Answer (score 2):

You must be looking for something like [Hybrid Crypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hybrid-crypto-js)

Comment: thanx a lot . i will use it and check it .

Comment: can i use this library of there is angular.js backend ?

Comment: Also if you find the solution useful you can accept and answer and upvote it. Thanks. Happy Coding :P

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using JSEncrypt https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt